# Pandoc - convert docx to .md with docx having word shapes

Tags: pandoc

I'm playing around with pandoc to see if it is able to convert all aspect of word doc to .md reliably. Looks like it handles lot of stuff pretty well such as table of contents, images, etc.. However, I am looking to see if it can also understand a diagram in word doc that has been made using combining multiple shapes of word. for, e.g. diagram like below in your word doc: 
[image]

when I do "pandoc --extract-media=. my.docx -o my.md" to convert to .md, mark down doc does not have any thing related to word shapes. Looks like it does not understand it. Is there any way to make pandoc smart enough to undestand word shapes ?

Answer (score 0):

No, pandoc cannot handle these. There are two issues for this on the pandoc issue tracker, [#4735](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4735), and [#2792](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2792).